# VCL style mac look style designer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

Recently I've been doing some research in to VCL Styling (Embarcadero XE2 for Delphi).
I can load and set the styles so that works fine.

Currently I'm exploring the VCL Style Designer and what I try to figure out is how can I move the minimize, maximize, resize, close and help button to the left instead of the current default right while the application text (caption of the form) is on the right.

I am at my whits end and hope some one can give me some pointers.

So basically what I try to 'emulate' is the Mac look on a Windows form.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: A simple workaround is to remove the window border and add the buttons yourself.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand where your going at. Could you please be a bit more specific??

Comment: I cannot help with the exact code but it should be possible to do something like Window.Border.Visible = False. Then you can make your own border by making a bar with your buttons in the top.

Comment: Ah okay I understand. That is one way to indeed fix the issue. But my main focus is to create it with VCL Style Designer. It's too bad I don't have the reputation to upload images yet. Then I could upload the image so you can see what I've created thus far.

Comment: It's a work around indeed, that is why I didn't post it as an answer. I'm not sure though whether it is possible to move the fixed buttons, as the standard border of a window in Windows is given by Windows and you only have a few options there, mainly because of consistency. Next question is then, does your UI use the standard Windows border? Otherwise, there is no other option than to remove it and build your own solution.

Comment: The VCL Styles are like a tile map. That uses images from a specified rectangular left, top, width, bottom field. I've posted the on imgur: http://imgur.com/RuH7R09.png

Comment: It's more than that visual appearance. The buttons behave differently. The middle one is not "maximize" in OS X, it's "minimize". And if you double-click on the form's header in OS X, it also triggers a "minimize" rather than "maximize". Even the "maximize" button doesn't do the same thing in OS X that "maximize" does in Windows. The analog to Windows' "maximize" button is the diagonal arrows in the top-right corner, and it's still not an exact duplicate.

Comment: David thanks for your comment it gives a tad more insight in the workings of osX. With the VCL Style editor you also have the option to disable (atleast thats what it looks like) buttons. I've posted the image on imgur.com you can see what I've created thus far.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thats not true: Diagonal arrows switch to **fullscreen** view (no border, no title, no taskbar, no dock, ...). The green button maximizes, but it is not a standard behaviour you know from windows and depends on the application itself (f.i. Safari behaves different than Firefox)

Comment: In your image the buttons are already on the left. If it is tile based you might have an allign option: button.allign = left

Comment: One would indeed think that Invalid_id. But I would like to see the form caption to be on the right side of the form. Setting the property of the caption to allign := right it doesn't work as suspected it doesn't move any further.

Comment: Is there a parent concept, maybe the parent of the caption is not correct. Another ugly hack would be to add spaces in front of the caption, but it's not trivial to get that right and probably always looks ugly.

Comment: There is a parent concept. And I've been trying to figure out how that works. But I'm not really sure how it works down to the children. I think it has some of the same flaws CSS 1.0 had. But that is just how it currently feels when working with the designer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz with the tile map it is possible to create your own buttons. You can have a map with several types of buttons (if you create the same look that the buttons have in osX then you can use them as such (since you can also assign actions to them))

Comment: @SirRufo The OP is trying to emulate the OS X window frame "look and feel" in Windows. It's more than just button placement. (In full screen view, the toolbar at the top and launch bar at the bottom also disappear. How much emulation is really wanted?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz for now I would be satisfied with just the buttons on the left and the text to the right. If more questions arise I can always ask a new question :)

Comment: It's probably worth re-evaluating *why* you are doing this.  It is generally a rather bad idea to try to change behaviour that people expect.  There is a reason that mac and windows users often dislike (and find difficult to operate) their counterparts' operating systems - because nothing is where they expect it to be, nor does it do what they expect!  If you make a windows application look and feel like a Mac application, Windows users are going to, largely, hate you for it and will not want to nor enjoy using your application.  I would seriously reconsider this.

Comment: @J... Your point if view is indeed a valid one. Although the reason I am researching the possibilities I just from the point of knowledge and  understand the limits of this system. So my question still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want accomplish is not related to the `VCL Style Designer`, instead you must create a custom form style hook.

Follow these steps.

1. Create (and register) a new form style hook descending from the `TFormStyleHook` class.
2. Override  the `PaintNC` method to draw the title buttons in the new positions.
3. Handle the `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`, `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_WM_NCLBUTTONUP` messages to detect the status of the title buttons (hot, pressed) and fire the actions (close, restore, maximize, minimize).

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer RRUZ. Is there any idea on when embarcadero might implement such a feature in there Style Designer?

Comment: How I said on my answer this is not related to the Style Designer. This can be done via a custom style hook.

Comment: I know what you meant RRUZ. And understand the 'current limitations' to the style designer. But what I meant in my previous comment is if embarcadero planning to implement such a feature to make it easier (less coding).